# PCA with ggplot in R becomes a Wilkinson dotplot/unit histogram based on colour input

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am new at R and ran into the following problem:

I have trying to make a PCA with ggplot() of RNAseq count data. I have two variables: celltype (4) and condition (2). I want to use 8 different colours for 8 different conditions in total, but it gets me this:

[image: Failed PCA with ggplot()]

The code I used:

```
df <- data.frame(meta, pca$x)
ggplot(df, aes(df[,27], df[,28])) +
  geom_point(aes(color = meta$colours)) +
  xlab(X) +
  ylab(Y) +
  ggtitle(Title_pca) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15)
        ) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Condition", 
                      labels = c("B cells + Abs", "B cells + no Abs", "CD4+ T cells + Abs", "CD4+ T cells + no Abs", "mDcs + Abs", "mDcs + no Abs", "Monocytes + Abs", "Monocytes + no Abs"), 
                      values = c("#FF0000", "#FF7A7A", "#FF9D00", "#FFC466", "#00B3FF", "#91DEFF", "#A200FF", "#CC73FF")
                      )
```

I want to get the dots like a scatterplot and not limited to the colour, of course. The whole scale_colour_manual argument works when I use it in plotPCA() of the DESeq2 package. This also confirms that my colours match the colours I used in the metadata. However, I don't know how I got these separations in the first place and I don't know how to remove them. So, my question to you is: What have I done incorrectly and how can I fix it?

Some additional information:

```
# Rstudio version:                    1.3.1093
# R version:                          4.0.2
# Platform:                           x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

#                                                                Version
# Packages:                           DESeq2                     1.30.0
#                                     ggplot2                    3.3.2
#                                     ggthemes                   4.2.0
```

Dataset organisation:

```
#           Celltype     bnAbs      colours
# Sample 1  B cells      Yes        "FF0000"
# Sample 2  Monocytes    No         "CC73FF"
```

Herein, the class of the Celltype and bnAbs column is factor, and of the colours column character.

As I previously said, I have only been doing this for a few weeks, so if you require more information to help me, I apologize and I will of course supply it asap.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You problem is one that is quite common when starting out with R and especially if you move from `base` plots to `ggplot2`. `ggplot2` evaluates the arguments and extract names implicitly. This is a sort of "non-standard" behaviour that is possible in R. To make this simple to understand, assume your data has columns named `PC1`, `PC2`... and `meta` (`meta` seems to be a `data.frame` with colours). The simplest (and recommended way) to specify arguments is to use these column names as arguments and provide your `data.frame` as the `data` argument. So

```
ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, col = colours)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Condition", 
                      labels = c("B cells + Abs", "B cells + no Abs", "CD4+ T cells + Abs", "CD4+ T cells + no Abs", "mDcs + Abs", "mDcs + no Abs", "Monocytes + Abs", "Monocytes + no Abs"), 
                      values = c("#FF0000", "#FF7A7A", "#FF9D00", "#FFC466", "#00B3FF", "#91DEFF", "#A200FF", "#CC73FF")
                      )
```

should be a minimum viable solution. Note that I specified the name without quotes `"`. This is the "non-standard" behaviour (that is implemented in `ggplot2` specifically). For this to work you need `df` to have a column `colour`. This should not specify the colours themselves (`"#FF0000"`), but instead be a factor indicating each group to be coloured (Similar to your "labels"). Since you're working with `RNAseq` you might have a column `RNA-name`, and this could be used.

This is what [STHDA tries to show here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually).

Comment: Hi Oliver, thank you for your response! I created a column in df with 8 levels for the 8 conditions and I tried out your code. However, nothing changed. Somehow, the dots are still separated by colour as shown in the graph I added to my post. Any suggestions on what I can do now?

Comment: No worries. I am not entirely sure where you are going wrong. You could try to reproduce your result with a small dataset (`iris` or `mtcars` is standard in R) and see if you could generate a small reproducible example? Currently I can't reproduce your problem. :-)